# Java get declaring class for an abstract class?

Tags: java, reflection

Does anyone know how to get the declaring / enclosing class of an abstract class in Java? In this case, I would like to get the anotherClass class from within someClass.

Example:

```
public class anotherClass extends someClass{
...
}

public abstract class someClass{
...
   this.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
}
```

Comment: Where do you know it is only one (i.e. *the* declaring class)? It could be hundreds!

Comment: What is the enclosing class `someClass` you mean?

Comment: It could be, but wouldn't those be their own instances of someClass as well?

Comment: From someClass I want to identify which class extended it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `this.getClass()` in an abstract class it will still return the class of the actual implementation. In your case calling `this.getClass()` will return `anotherClass`, which is what you want if I am not wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity then how would you actually get someClass from the abstract class someClass?

Comment: @Kevin I tried `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` and it worked - it displayed `someClass`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this without using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass%28%29)

Comment: Apparently you can. see Boris Strandjev's answer.

Comment: @kevin thats not the same, it might well be what you want, but the question was slightly different

Comment: Either way I've accepted his answer as it does what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the reflection solution, you can force people to pass you themselves with some curiously recurring generics, like the following:

```
class AnotherClass extends SomeClass<AnotherClass> {
    public AnotherClass() {
        super(AnotherClass.class);
    }
}

abstract class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>> {
    final Class<T> enclosing;
    public SomeClass(Class<T> c) {
        enclosing = c;
    }
}
```